# not able to enter text in webview on nexus 4 android 4.2.2

Tags: android, android-webview, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am trying to open a webpage inside web view and it is working fine on andoid 4.1.2 and below, but when I tried the same code in android 4.2.2 i.e nexus 4 it is not taking any input from keyboard.

When i click on any edit text on web page keyboard gets open and it also show the focus on edit text, but as soon as I press any character keyboard focus lost from the edit text and nothing gets typed on the field. be low is my code

```
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        mWebView.clearHistory();
        mWebView.clearFormData();
        mWebView.clearCache(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl(strUrl);
        mWebView.requestFocus();


/**
     * webview client
     */
    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        // show the web page in webview but not in web browser
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if ( !getSuceessParams(url) )
                view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view, HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {
            handler.proceed("checkin", "4good");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            System.out.println("onPageFinished " + url);
            context.removeDialog(0);
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            System.out.println("onPageStarted " + url);
            Fragment fragment = context.getLastFragment();
            if ( fragment.getTag() == "campaign_donation_web_fragment" ) {
                CheckinLibraryActivity.strProgressMessage = "Loading..";
                context.showDialog(0);
            }
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }
    }
```

I am getting following error

```
****Should not happen: no rect-based-test nodes found
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and it seemed to be fixed by not using the SwiftKey keyboard instead using the Google keyboard. http://support.swiftkey.net/forums/116693-2-bug-reports/suggestions/3808949-phonegap-app

Answer (score 0):

In my case `TabHost` from a previous fragment in back stack was stealing the focus on every key press. Here's how I fixed it:

```
tabHost.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(new OnAttachStateChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View v) {}

  @Override
  public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View v) {
    tabHost.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnTouchModeChangeListener(tabHost);
  }
});
```

See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2516 for more on the topic.